# Determine the remainder in the division of $ a_ {2019} $ by 2019

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

Consider the sequence set by $ a_1 = 0 $, $ a_2 = 1 $, and for $ n \geq 3 $ $$ a_n = (n-1) (a_ {n-1} + a_ {n-2}) $$ Determine the remainder in the division of $ a_ {2019} $ by 2019

a) 1

b)2

c) 2017

d)2018

Can anyone give me any tips for this problem?

Attemp: a3 = 2 * ( 1 + 0) = 2

a4 = 3 * ( 2 + 1) = 9 , r = 1

a5 = 4 * ( 9 +  2) = 44, r = 4

a6 = 5 * ( 44 + 9) = 265, r = 1

a7 = 6 * ( 265 + 44) = 1854, r = 6

Comment: tip:  calculate the first several values of $a_n$ and look at $a_n \bmod n$

Comment: Okay, I figured it out. Is this to see a pattern?

Comment: Yes, with enough values you should see a pattern (depending if $n$ is odd or even)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you show $a_n-na_{n-1}=a_{n-2}-(n-2)a_{n-3}$?

It follows then that $a_{2019}-2019a_{2018}=a_3-3a_2=-1.$

Comment: You can Also mod all by 3 and get the pattern 0,1,2,0,2,1,...

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee:  I think you are correct, but does that help solve the original problem?

Comment: it limits it to $b$ or $d$ without  having to do mod 2019 or mod 673 arithmetic.