# Determine the remainder in the division of $ a_ {2019} $

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, solution-verification

Consider the sequence set by $ a_1 = 0 $, $ a_2 = 1 $, and for $ n \geq 3 $ $$ a_n = (n-1) (a_ {n-1} + a_ {n-2}) $$Determine the remainder in the division of $ a_ {2019} $ by 2019

a) 1

b)2

c) 2017

d)2018

$a_n-na_{n-1}=- (a_{n-1}-(n-1)a_{n-2})=(a_{n-2}-(n-2)a_{n-3})=...=(-1)^{n-1} (a_1-a_0)=(-1)^{n-1}$

So $a_{2019}=2019a_{2018}+(-1)^{2018} \to a_{2019} \equiv 1 \pmod {2019}$

Correct?

Comment: $a_3=2(a_2+a_1)=2(1+0)=2\neq(-1)^2$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson What does that mean? Wrong?

Comment: See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3477680/determine-the-remainder-in-the-division-of-a-2019-by-2019/3477750#3477750)

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were claiming $a_n=(-1)^{n-1}$. Never mind.

Comment: what is $a_0$ ?

Comment: There is an error in your calculations because $a_0$ was never defined, so you should instead stop with $a_2$ and $a_1$ which means that the exponent would be n-2, not n-1, so you get an exponent of 2017, and an answer of 2018

Comment: Hm, it is suspicious that this is nearly a duplicate of [Determine the remainder in the division of $a_{2019}$
by 2019](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3477680/272831)...